# Unity: Dimensions of color surface does not match dimensions of depth surface

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, rendertexture

I am receiving the error, "Dimensions of color surface does not match dimensions of depth surface" whenever I attempt to use my screenshot code, without any callstack or anything further insight of what I am doing wrong.

I have a separate camera from my main camera, whose purpose is to take screenshots at different angles.  Hierarchy as such:

[image: Hierarchy]

- The main camera captures the 3D scene just like a normal main camera would, including post-processing components.  No HDR or MSAA.
  [image: Post-processing components]
- The GUI camera captures just the UI layer.  Nothing enabled except MSAA.
- The canvas and image are simply a watermark, rendered by the GUI camera.

I point both the main camera and GUI camera to the same target render texture.  When ready to take a screenshot, I enable the camera components, thus Unity takes over and tells them to render the frame.  In the `OnRenderImage` callback, I disable the camera so it can be used again, I remove the render texture I previously assigned, extract the pixels, and save it as a PNG.

In a separate test, this all seems to work as intended.  No error messages.  However, when playing the full game, suddenly I receive the dimensions errors upon each screenshot.

I have read that `RenderTexture.IsCreated` will test if the render texture is still available.  Supposed, it will be set to false due to a large variety of events, such as window changes.  I have made it impossible to even get the reference to the render texture without it checking if the `IsCreated` bool is true.  I have also tested if the render texture matches its `Descriptor` property, out of paranoia.  All of these checks succeed.

I don't know what to look at next.

What is SUPER strange is I have a GIF generator, using quite similar code, that's much more complicated, and it does not suffer from this problem.

Has anyone dealt with this error before?  Any hints at all?

Comment: Can you show us your code? The more precisely we can replicate your exact situation, the better we can test solutions to make sure they'll work for you.

Comment: Apologies, it will take some time for me to make an example, probably requiring me to make a copy in a blank project so I can share it.  Unfortunately, I have some very tight deadlines, and may not be able to get to it soon.  If you have seen the error above and have any recommendations, I'd like to hear them in the meantime.